# Bootstrap 3 nav links not inline on large screen

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, parent-child

I am changing the navigation of a parent theme to the bootstrap default (I am creating a child theme, and the parent theme already utilizes bootstrap)
The parent theme already has the bootstrap code in the functions.php (and a bunch of other nav js files I don't need) So i copied the header.php into the child theme and replaced the nav info with the default.

Everything works fine functionally, except when on normal sized screens the links stack on top of the other instead of beside. and the :hover states (background colour) light up the entire width of nav-bar. When I used the default code (not linked to wordpress menu) it works fine. But when I add the wp code it stacks the links.

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
                    <?php /* Primary navigation */
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu' => 'top_menu',
                        'depth' => 2,
                        'container' => false,
                        'menu_class' => 'nav',
                        //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                        );
                    ?>
                </div>
```

I didn't change anything in the style.css or functions.php except added the code line

```
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
```

because the parent theme didn't have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add navbar-nav to your menu class

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
    <?php /* Primary navigation */
        wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu' => 'top_menu',
        'depth' => 2,
        'container' => false,
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
        //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
        'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
        );
    ?>
</div>
```